# how to access a key in a dictionary using map function

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary in python like this

```
MB_AC_InvStyle = {
"Absolute Return_High": ('OICR Flessibili', 'Flessibile'),
"Absolute Return_Medium" : ('OICR Flessibili', 'Flessibile'),
"Bond_Convertible" : ('OICR Obbligazionari', 'Obbligazionario'),
"Bond_Inflation Linked" : ('OICR Obbligazionari', 'Obbligazionario'),
"Bond_Long Only" : ('OICR Obbligazionari', 'Obbligazionario'),
"Equity_Long Only" : ('OICR Azionari', 'Azionario'),
"Mixed_Aggressive" : ('OICR Flessibili', 'Flessibile'),
"Mixed_Balanced" : ('OICR Flessibili', 'Flessibile'),
"Mixed_Conservative" : ('OICR Flessibili', 'Flessibile'),
"Mixed_Flexible" : ('OICR Flessibili', 'Flessibile')
}
```

I want to extract the values under key 1
`MB_AC_InvStyle["Absolute Return_High"][1]` 
from the dictionary using map function but it doesn't work:

```
df01['MB_CategoriaStrumento'] = np.where(df01['Inst. Sub-type'] =='Mutual    Fund',
                                     df01['Investment Sub-Style'].map (MB_AC_InvStyle[0][1]),
                                     df01['MB_CategoriaStrumento'].map(MB_AssetClass))
```

How can I access dictionary values using map function and the dictionary?
N.B. The filed 'Investment Sub-Style' is the key of dict obviously.
thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code snippet as reference to access the dictionary value, 1st element.

```
MB_AC_InvStyle = { "Absolute Return_High": ('OICR Flessibili', 'Flessibile'), "Absolute Return_Medium" : ('OICR Flessibili', 'Flessibile'), "Bond_Convertible" : ('OICR Obbligazionari', 'Obbligazionario'), "Bond_Inflation Linked" : ('OICR Obbligazionari', 'Obbligazionario'), "Bond_Long Only" : ('OICR Obbligazionari', 'Obbligazionario'), "Equity_Long Only" : ('OICR Azionari', 'Azionario'), "Mixed_Aggressive" : ('OICR Flessibili', 'Flessibile'), "Mixed_Balanced" : ('OICR Flessibili', 'Flessibile'), "Mixed_Conservative" : ('OICR Flessibili', 'Flessibile'), "Mixed_Flexible" : ('OICR Flessibili', 'Flessibile') }

first_elem = list(map(lambda x: x + ': ' +MB_AC_InvStyle[x][1], MB_AC_InvStyle))
print first_elem
```